# My employer asks me to charge his customer for more hours than I put in; am I earning haram this way?

Tags: halal-haram, work

My employer wants to charge his customer more hours than he's having me put in. I'm asked to submit more hours than I'm putting in. In case the customer asks I'm supposed to lie.

Am I earning haram this way?